# Switch state changing is not working - Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the state of switch and its implementation by taping another switch. I tried but failed.
Can anyone help?

Here's my Activity.java

```
//first switch

flw_Rate_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)  {

            if (isChecked) {

                    //lqd_followed_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

          //lqd_followed_switch.setChecked(!lqd_followed_switch.isChecked());

                    flow_rate_switch_txt.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                    mlineData = generateLineData(rate);
                    data.setData(mlineData);
                    combinedChart.setData(data);

                    combinedChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(4); // allow 4 values to be displayed at once on the x-axis, not more
                    combinedChart.moveViewToX(4);
                    combinedChart.animateY(2000);
                    combinedChart.invalidate();


                } else {
                    //elseFlowRate();
                    flow_rate_switch_txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    String label = "Flow Rate";

                    boolean indicator = data.removeDataSet(lineData1.getDataSetByLabel(label, true));
                    combinedChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    combinedChart.invalidate();
                    combinedChart.animateX(1000);
                }
            }

        });


//2nd switch


        lqd_followed_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                 lqd_followed_switch_txt.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));



                    mlineData = generateLineData1(foll);
                    data.setData(mlineData);
                    combinedChart.setData(data);

                    combinedChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(4); // allow 4 values to be displayed at once on the x-axis, not more
                    combinedChart.moveViewToX(4);
                    combinedChart.animateY(2000);
                    combinedChart.invalidate();

                } else {

                    lqd_followed_switch_txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    String label = "Liquid Followed";
                    boolean indicator = data.removeDataSet(lineData2.getDataSetByLabel(label, true));
                    combinedChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    combinedChart.invalidate();

                }
            }

        });
```

When I tap on first switch it runs "if" block, on same time when i tap on 2nd switch it runs "if" block of 2nd switch but it must not keep running switch 1st's "if" clause block rather than it should automatically run "else" block of switch 1st.

Comment: In short problem is that by taping on 2nd switch "else" block of 1st switch should also b run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
```

is an event listener which means it won't be triggered if the event (checked or unchecked) does not occur.

If you want to update the other UI component, you should call something like below:

```java
flw_Rate_switch.setChecked(false);
```

or

```java
flw_Rate_switch.setChecked(true);
```